# Chromecast with Google TV: No HDMI-CEC entries in Logcat

Tags: hdmi, logging, chromecast

Trying to get as much control as it's possible from the TV's *(LG LF630V)* remote for the connected **Chromecast with Google TV.**

The HDMI-CEC definitely works on Chromecast, as e.g., **→ ←​ ↓ ↑ [OK] [Back]** buttons are received from the TV remote. The problem is that I need even more (e.g. *[Home]* button is not implemented), so I've tried to intercept HDMI-CEC commands from **Logcat entry,** using *Tasker.* But absolutely no **[HdmiCecControl]** entries do appear in *Logcat,* unless (rare) CEC errors.

What I'm doing wrong? Should I explicitly enable HDMI-CEC entries in Logcat? If so, how sould I enable it? Or there is a missing permission here? Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Android TC contains an HDME CEC service. I assume the log messages you see are from this service. I don't think it is configurable what is logged and what not. Thus the only way would be to change the service or to try to access the HDMI-CEC service using the app API which requires to develop an own app respectively Tasker plugin. But that seem to require a bit reverse engineering as the HDMI-CEC API doesn't seem to be documented. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47892639/150978

Comment: So, as I understand there are low chances to make HDMI CEC logging more verbose. Reverse engineering is out of question, as there are smart remotes (IR + BT) as low as €50 (SofaBaton U1) for controlling both the CC and the TV. I hoped there was an easy workaround. Thanks!